# Laravel showing image path from storage/app folder

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to display an image stored in my Storage folder but it showing a broken link icon.
Here's the controller

```
`public function getUserImage($filename)
{
    $file = Storage::disk('public')->get($filename);
    return new Response($file, 200);
}`
```

Here is the img src in my view

```
<img src="{{ route('account.image', ['filename' => $user->name . '-' . $user->id . '.jpg']) }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
```

Here is my route code

`Route::get('/user/{filename}',[
    'uses'  => 'UserController@getUserImage',
    'as'    => 'account.image'
]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send a proper 'Content-Type' header for the response in case of sending images. The code may look like:

```
public function getUserImage($filename)
{
    $response = Response::make(Storage::disk('public')->get($filename));
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    return response;
}
```